# C++: sizeof(member) in the definition of the class

Tags: c++, c++11, sizeof

Is the following code well-formed?

```
#include <cstddef>

struct Test
{
    int      member;
    static constexpr const size_t   Size1 = sizeof(member);
    static constexpr const size_t   Size2 = sizeof(decltype(member));
    static constexpr const size_t   Size3 = sizeof(Test::member);
};
```

The problem is `sizeof(member)` used in the definition of the class itself. All `Size1`, `Size2` and `Size3` initializers went fine with gcc, clang and newer MSVC. But MSVC 14 isn't happy with `Size1` (the other two are ok). It says:

> error C2327: 'Test::member': is not a type name, static, or enumerator

which baffles me, because `member` (whether qualified or not) seems a valid expression in the context of that class.

So, should I take this as a bug in older MSVC, or is such error message justified?

Comment: `sizeof()` does not require any header especially `<cstddef>`, not clear why you put it into your example

Comment: Not really a bug per se. Just a not yet implemented change from C++03.

Comment: @Slava, I suppose `size_t` does require a header.

Comment: @StoryTeller, thank you for the redirection to a duplicate question. It didn't show up in the list of automatically suggested similar questions...

Comment: Np. I only remembered it because I posted an answer there. You did ask this question very well. I hope it will help others find the answers there.